# change ip address from the available addresses of the network in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip, python-requests

Actually Iam trying to extract data from a site.But it ends with

> Maximum tries exceeded Error

I have tried sleep() method also but didnt work.so how to find all the available addresses for my machine.

I found this example in [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/ipaddress.html)

```
net4 = ipaddress.ip_network('192.0.2.0/24')
for x in net4.hosts():
    print(x)  

192.0.2.1
192.0.2.2
192.0.2.3
192.0.2.4 ...
```

**can I use this for changing my ip every 10 seconds ?**

I am confused. what is `192.0.2.0/24` here and what am I supposed to give in the place of `192.0.2.0/24` and how can I know my machine's ip address or ip_network so I can give the value in `net4 = ipaddress.ip_network('192.0.2.0/24')`

Comment: What do you think changing you  local ip is going to do?

Comment: I think the site is preventing too many requests from same ip address so I thought of changing the ip address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it says **Maximum tries exceeded**, then the system is doing one of two things:

1. It's using your session information to track how many times you've tried - in this case, you can just start a new `requests.session()` to fix this
2. It's using your external IP address - in this case, changing your internal IP address won't make much of a difference

Either way, changing your internal IP address won't affect the outcome of your script

Comment: it is not consistent.any ways I'll try starting a new session().Thank you